# How to add Foldername infront of a File instead of creating one?

Tags: c#, io, directory, subdirectory

I tried to copy everything in an folder to an other folder, but i try to Not Create a subfolder in the targetpath instead i try to take the name of the subfolder in the sourcepath and add it infront of the tagetpath and set a underscore betwen them

Exaple:

```
sourcefolder
├file1.txt
├subfolder1
|└file2.txt
└subfolder2
 ├subfolder3
 |└file3.txt
 └subfolder4
  └file4.txt
```

Gets to:

```
 targetfolder:
 ├file1.txt
 ├subfolder1_file2.txt
 ├subfolder2_subfolder3_file3.txt
 ├subfolder2_subfolder4_file4.txt
```

Currently i just get it with folders:

```
foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath));
}

foreach (string srcPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    newPath = srcPath.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath);
    File.Copy(srcPath, newPath, true);
}
```

And i tried it with :

```
private void showDeletefiles(string filePath)
    {
        string[] installfiles = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
        string[] subfolders = Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
        string appdatafolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        int i = 0;

        foreach (string file in installfiles)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            string fileextension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

                if (!File.Exists(sourcefoldervalueLabel + file) && fileextension != ".manifest")
                {
                    File.Copy(filePath + fileName, appdatafolder+ fileName, true);
                }
                if (subfolders.Length >= 0)
                {
                    string[] subfolderfiles = Directory.GetFiles(subfolders[i]);
                    string foldername = Path.GetFileName(subfolders[i]);
                    i++;


                    foreach (string subfiles in subfolderfiles)
                    {
                        File.Copy(filePath + fileName, appdatafolder + foldername + "_" + subfiles, true);
                    }
                }
            }
       }
```

The problem is i go only into the first "subfolder"

Comment: what have you tried? It should be rather easy using the methods from the `Path` class

Comment: You have a ambiguity when `subfolder1_file2.txt` file exist in parent folder and `file2.txt` exist in nested folder named `subfolder1`.

Comment: Also I'm not sure where is the problem?

Comment: Just check if it is sub-folder in the destination folder, then add underscore in front of filename. It should be simple

Comment: w8 i will change the Code  and @Sriramsakthivel i dont understand what do you mean where is the ambiguity

Comment: Assume you have a file named `subfolder1_file2.txt` in a folder, and also a nested folder named `subfolder1`. Inside that subfolder1 you have `file2.txt`. So using your logic both the files will be named as `subfolder1_file2.txt` Isn't it? What will you do in that case?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That wold be never the problem beqause the folder gets created befor i run the code and deleted after there are any other files in this folder :)

Comment: I edited it and I hope i wrote the code right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my Question by myself:

The Code:

```
    string[] installfiles = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
        string[] subfolders = Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
        string appdatafolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        int i = 0;

        foreach (string file in installfiles)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            string fileextension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

            if (!Directory.Exists(appdatafolder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(appdatafolder);
            }
                File.Copy(filePath + fileName, appdatafolder + fileName, true);
            if (subfolders.Length >= 0 && i < subfolders.Length)
            {
                string[] subfolderfiles = Directory.GetFiles(subfolders[i]);
                string foldername = Path.GetFileName(subfolders[i]);
                i++;
                foreach (string subfiles in subfolderfiles)
                {
                    string subfilesname = Path.GetFileName(subfiles);
                    File.Copy(filePath + fileName, appdatafolder + foldername + "_" + subfilesname, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is how i needed it hopefully it helps you out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a `FileInfo` object from each of your strings and extract the proper information from there. This should work, assuming you have a path of "DirectoryLetter:\Folder\Files" or "DirectoryLetter:\Files". Note this is obviously not the most efficient code with the use of `string.Replace` and of course this will have to be tested with all your common scenarios.

```
var fileInfos = Directory.GetFiles(@"DirectoryToTraverseHere", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                         .Select(file => new FileInfo(file));

foreach (var fileInfo in fileInfos)
{
   string newFileInfo;
   if (fileInfo.Directory.Parent.Name == fileInfo.Directory.Root.Name)
   {
      newFileInfo = string.Format("{0}_{1}", fileInfo.Directory.FullName, fileInfo.Name);
   }
   else
   {
      newFileInfo = string.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", fileInfo.Directory.Parent.FullName, 
                                              fileInfo.Directory.Name, 
                                              fileInfo.Name);
   }

   File.Copy(fileInfo.FullName, Path.Combine("TargetDirectory", newFileName));
}
```

Comment: im sorry but i get just `C_Example_targetfolder` but  i actually searched for `C:\\Example\\targetfolder\\subfolder_file1` it could also be me  so i'm not here to blame you

Comment: Didn't you want underscores instead of backslashes?

Comment: yea but only in the last subfolders... dind't i asked correctly? ._.